# Unable to assign a global variable to a drop down change event using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I see that variations of this question has been asked several times before but none of the solutions seem to work for me unfortunately. I'm still a beginner in JavaScript hence I'm not sure what's happening here to debug this properly and what exactly to read up in the documentation.

Basically, I want to access and store the selected value of a drop down list inside a change event handler.

In my current approach, I am able to output the change event *inside* the event handler. But I cannot seem to assign it to a global variable *outside* of it, which I require for some other parts in my code.

Here is my MWE:

```
let dd = document.getElementById('dropDownMenu')
let dropDownChoice;

dd.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  dropDownChoice = e.target.value;
  console.log(dropDownChoice); // This outputs the selected item whenever the drop down is changed
});

console.log(dropDownChoice) // This does not output anything
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not outputting anything becasue that line is executed before you make a selection. If you add a button and call a function by clicking it after you select, you will see that the value is there:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => console.log(dropDownChoice))
```